# Combine dragging and animating drag position on click (animate x.set())

Tags: reactjs, framerjs, framer-motion

For a client we're building horizontally dragging rows of media items. Dragging horizontally using Framer-Motion works great, but I can't animate the x position on the click of a button.

This is the general idea:

[image]

This is the component as I currently have it (I removed style, etc. for brevity):

```js
const HorizontalScroll = ({ children }) => {
  const x = useMotionValue(0);

  function onLeftClick() {
    const xPos = x.get();

    if (Math.round(xPos) === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const newXPosition = xPos + 600;

    x.set(newXPosition > 0 ? 0 : newXPosition);
  }

  function onRightClick() {
    const xPos = x.get();

    const newXPosition = xPos - 600;

    x.set(newXPosition < -2000 ? -2000 : newXPosition);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onLeftClick}
      >
        Left
      </button>

      <motion.div
        drag="x"
        dragConstraints={{ left: -2000, right: 0 }}
        initial={false}
        style={{ width: 2000, x }}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onRightClick}
      >
        Right
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

So I do `x.set()` when clicking either left or right on the arrows. Doing `x.set()` works, but it isn't animated.

Instead of `const x = useMotionValue(0)` I could use `useSpring` or `useTransform`, but that breaks the dragging behaviour.

So in short, I want to animate the `x.set()`, but I've no idea how to do that. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally posted my question and I find the answer to my own question in under an hour...

In case anyone has the same edge case question. What I came up with (and this is by no means the most elegant solution) is using `useAnimation`. My component currently looks like this:

```js
const translateXForElement = (element) => {
  const transform = element.style.transform;

  if (!transform || transform.indexOf('translateX(') < 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  const extractTranslateX = transform.match(/translateX\((-?\d+)/);

  return extractTranslateX && extractTranslateX.length === 2
    ? parseInt(extractTranslateX[1], 10)
    : 0;
}

const HorizontalScroll = ({ children }) => {
  const dragRef = useRef(null);
  const animation = useAnimation();

  function onLeftClick() {
    const xPos = translateXForElement(dragRef.current);
    const newXPosition = xPos + 600;

    animation.start({
      x: newXPosition > 0 ? 0 : newXPosition,
    });
  }

  function onRightClick() {
    const xPos = translateXForElement(dragRef.current);
    const newXPosition = xPos - 600;

    animation.start({
      x: newXPosition < -2000 ? -2000 : newXPosition,
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onLeftClick}
      >
        Left
      </button>

      <motion.div
        drag="x"
        dragConstraints={{ left: -2000, right: 0 }}
        initial={false}
        animate={animation}
        style={{ width: 2000, x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
        ref={dragRef}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onRightClick}
      >
        Right
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I couldn't find a (nice) solution to retrieve the current `translateX` for an element, so I did a regex on `element.style.transform` for now. It's too bad `useAnimation()` doesn't allow retrieving the `x` (or I'm missing something).

Of course if you've anything to approve in my code, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I found you can just keep track of this in a variable

```
const HorizontalScroll = ({ children }) => {
  const dragRef = useRef(null);
    const xPos = useRef(0);
  const animation = useAnimation();

  function onLeftClick() {
    const newXPosition = xPos.current + 600;

    animation.start({
      x: newXPosition > 0 ? 0 : newXPosition,
    });
  }

  function onRightClick() {
    const newXPosition = xPos.current - 600;

    animation.start({
      x: newXPosition < -2000 ? -2000 : newXPosition,
    });
  }

    function onUpdate(latest){
        xPos.current = latest.x;
    }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onLeftClick}
      >
        Left
      </button>

      <motion.div
        drag="x"
        dragConstraints={{ left: -2000, right: 0 }}
        initial={false}
                onUpdate={onUpdate}
        animate={animation}
        style={{ width: 2000, x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
        ref={dragRef}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onRightClick}
      >
        Right
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```